# Zitat - Heinrich Heine

Tags: literature

Ich bin im Buch *Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#* auf folgendes Zitat vom deutschen Dichter Heinrich Heine gestoßen:

> The weather-cock on the church spire, though made of iron, would soon be broken by the storm-wind if it did not understand the noble art of turning to every wind.

Anschließend habe ich nach dessen deutschem Ursprung gesucht. Leider konnte ich die Originalquelle nicht finden. Kennt jemand die Originalquelle und kann mir diese nennen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Zitat vom Heinrich Heine ist;

[image]

> Die Wetterfahnen verlassen sich auf ihr berühmtes Talent der
> Vielseitigkeit in der Bewegung; sie fürchten nicht die ärgsten Stürme,
> da sie immer verstanden, sich nach jedem Luftzug zu drehen.

Source; Sämtliche Werke, Band 5
Cover
Heinrich Heine (Seite: 308)

Comment: Vielen Dank für den Beitrag. Wo dürfte ich es finden?

Comment: @AyoubFalah Bitte sieh meine bearbeitete Antwort ;)

Comment: Dieses Zitat ist zwar ähnlich gestrickt, weicht jedoch an mehreren Stellen von der o.g. englischen Version ab.

Comment: @ParaDice umso erstaunlicher, dass es den "Haken" bekommen hat...

Comment: War wohl ein Fall von "nicht gut, aber gut genug". ;)

Comment: @tofro Die Frage ist nach einer Referenz, wo man das Zitat finden kann(Es geht nicht um die Übersetzung). Dieser Antwort war die Erste, die meine Frage richtig beantwortet hat. Aus diesem Grund war als korrekt markiert.

Comment: @AyoubFalah Schau' dir die Zitate in den beiden Antworten noch einmal genau an - Dieses hier ist *ähnlich*, aber anders (z.B. fehlt die Erwähnung des Eisens). Die Antwort von ParaDice enthält - aus einem anderen Band der Gesamtausgabe - dein Zitat sehr exakt.

Comment: @tofro die Quelle, die ich gezeigt habe, ist 35 Jahre älter als die andere. D.h es ist möglich, dass das Zitat sich in der Zwischenzeit geändert hat. Z.b jemand (oder der Autor selbst) hat die Erwähnung des Eisens hinzugefügt, um die Wetterfahne besser zu beschreiben.

Comment: This is apparently not the source of the cited statement. The answer of @ParaDice seems to be the correct one. That's why I gave -1 here.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Impliziert die Richtigkeit der Quelle der anderen Antwort, dass diese hier falsch ist? Vor allem wenn das Buch heißt "Sämtliche Werke Band 5", wäre es nicht denkbar dass dies Reisebilder enthält? Da fände ein "-1" *nicht* verdient.

Comment: @c.p. Es ist ja im englischen Zitat eindeutig vom Wetterhahn die Rede, nicht von der Wetterfahne. Ja, die Richtigkeit der anderen Belegstelle beweist, dass dieser Nachweis hier falsch ist.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Wenn du die Quellenangabe der anderen Antwort klickst, wirst du sehen, dass es aus dem Jahr 1969. Der Autor ist im 1856 gestorben (vor mehr als 100 Jahre als diese Ausgabe). Wenn du die Bücher von Shakespear liest, sind die Wörter total anders als das Original. In dieser Frage geht es nicht um eins-zu-eins Übersetzung, sondern die Quelle des Zitats.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Das sind einfach zwei verschiedene Stellen bei Heine. Deine klingt so ähnlich, aber Quelle der gesuchten Übersetzung ins englische ist zweifelsohne die andere Stelle. Daher ist deine Antwort einfach nicht korrekt.

Comment: Guter Fund, aber nicht der richtige. Ich verstehe nicht, warum Du dagegen argumentierst.

Comment: @CarstenS Ich argumentiere dagegen nicht. Wenn du mich fragen würdest, würde ich auch die andere Antwort als Solution markieren. Aber das macht diese Antwort automatisch nicht falsch aber zeigt, dass die andere Antwort passender ist.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das kann sein, aber auch nicht. Meine Antwort ist nur eine Theorie, die behauptet, dass die eigentlichen Quelle des oben genannten Zitat ist dies.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Und diese Theorie ist mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit falsch. Die Metapher Wetterfahne / Wetterhahn ist nicht so originell (findet man etwa auch schon bei Luther), dass man nun einen genetischen Zusammenhang zwischen den beiden Heine-Stellen annehmen muss, um das mehrfache Auftauchen der Metapher bei ihm zu erklären.

Comment: Actually @jonathan.scholbach is right here. Amongst many other 19th century editions the **1886** Cotta edition of "Heinrich Heine: Sämtliche Werke" contains on page 268 an **identical text** passage as was quoted by ParaDice. Heine wrote in contemporary  German. It is very unlikely anybody publishes his work altered in any way. The passage quoted in the answer above **is not the source for the English translation in question**.

Comment: @AyoubFalah Von den Kommentaren habe ich verstanden, dass die Quelle, die ich gegeben habe, ist nicht richtig. Du weisst aber, es wäre besser wenn du die andere Antwort als Solution markierst.

Answer (score 13):

> man muß alsdann billig bedenken, daß derjenige, der sich auf einer gewissen Höhe behaupten will, ebenso den Umständen nachgeben muß, wie der Hahn auf dem Kirchturm, den, obgleich er von Eisen ist, jeder Sturmwind zerbrechen und herabschleudern würde, wenn er trotzig unbeweglich bliebe und nicht die edle Kunst verstände sich nach jedem Winde zu drehen. 
>   Heinrich Heine: *Reisebilder*. Kapitel 115.

http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/reisebilder-393/115